# How to Use a Select Statement in a Parameterized Insert Into Statement

Tags: vb.net, oledb, insert-into, sql

I am trying this code but I am getting an error:

```
Dim cmd3 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Criteria (Calculation, [Interval], Weight) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", Nordeen_Investing_3.con)
    cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Calculation", Calculation)
    cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Interval]", Interval)
    cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Weight", "(SELECT (Avg(C." & Calculation & " * G.Growth) - Avg(C." & Calculation & ") * Avg(G.Growth)) / (StDevP(C." & Calculation & ") * StDevP(G.Growth)) AS Weight FROM " & Calculation & " AS C INNER JOIN " & Growth_Rate & " AS G " & On_Statement & ")")
    cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

This is the error message:

`Data type mismatch in criteria expression.`

The problem lies in this line of code:

`cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Weight", "(SELECT (Avg(C." & Calculation & " * G.Growth) - Avg(C." & Calculation & ") * Avg(G.Growth)) / (StDevP(C." & Calculation & ") * StDevP(G.Growth)) AS Weight _
FROM " & Calculation & " AS C _
INNER JOIN " & Growth_Rate & " AS G _
" & On_Statement & ")")`

If I substitute the `Select Statement` with the value that the `Select Statement` produces then the code runs fine.

How can I get this to work?

**UPDATE**
Based upon the suggestion below I have changed my code to this:

```
Dim cmd3 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Criteria (Calculation, [Interval], Weight) VALUES (?, ?, (SELECT (Avg(C." & Calculation & " * G.Growth) - Avg(C." & Calculation & ") * Avg(G.Growth)) / (StDevP(C." & Calculation & ") * StDevP(G.Growth)) AS Weight FROM " & Calculation & " AS C INNER JOIN " & Growth_Rate & " AS G " & On_Statement & "))", Nordeen_Investing_3.con)
    cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Calculation", Calculation)
    cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Interval]", Interval)
    cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

I received this error when I ran the new code:

`Unspecified error`

Comment: You should put the query that calculates the third parameter within the main query, not as a parameter

Comment: @EstebanElverdin I took your advice (see original post update).  I received this error `Unspecified error`.

Comment: @EstebanElverdin If I run the select statement by itself it returns a value with no errors.  But when I add it to my `INSERT INTO statement` I get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to insert data through a subquery, the way you are making the query is not right

It should be something like

```
INSERT INTO table1
SELECT id FROM table2
WHERE ...
```

In your particular case, the query for the OleDBCommand will look like

```
"INSERT INTO Criteria (Calculation, [Interval], Weight)
SELECT ?, ?, (Avg(C." & Calculation & " * G.Growth) - Avg(C." & Calculation & ") * Avg(G.Growth)) / (StDevP(C." & Calculation & ") * StDevP(G.Growth)) AS Weight FROM " & Calculation & " AS C INNER JOIN " & Growth_Rate & " AS G " & On_Statement
```